# Hibernate, вопрос про Join'ы

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Все никак не могу понять логику того, как JoinColumn определяет какую колонку с какой надо связать.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BETS")
public class Bet {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "id_bet") // Primary Key
private int id_bet;

@Column(name = "id_result")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_result")
private int id_result;

@Column(name = "bet_on")
private String bet_on;

@Column(name = "amount")
private int amount;

public Bet() {
}

public void setResultId(int id_result) {
    this.id_result = id_result;
}

public void setBetOn(String bet_on) {
    this.bet_on = bet_on;
}

public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public int getBetId() {
    return id_bet;
}

public int getResultId() {
    return id_result;
}

public String getBetOn() {
    return bet_on;
}

public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
```

И вот этого:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RESULTS")
public class Result {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "id_result")  //Primary Key
private static short id_result;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "id_event")
private short id_event;

@Column(name = "winner")
private String winner;

@Column(name = "multiplier")
private double multiplier;

public void setEventId(short id_event) {
    this.id_event = id_event;
}

public void setWinner(String winner) {
    this.winner = winner;
}

public void multiplier(double multiplier) {
    this.multiplier = multiplier;
}

public int getResultId() {
    return id_result;
}

public int getEventId() {
    return id_event;
}

public String getWinner() {
    return winner;
}

public double getMultiplier() {
    return multiplier;
}
```

Надо связать классы по id_result(Bets) -> id_result(Results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коротко: в  `@JoinColumn` вы указываете имя колонки, в которой находится id присоединяемой сущности.

---

Используя аннотацию `@ManyToOne` вы просите `hibernate` положить в это поле набор соответствующих объектов.

Поэтому вам надо поменять:

```
private int id_result;
```

на:

```
private Result result;
```

В этом случае `hibernate` будет вытаскивать объект `Bet` и добавлять к нему объект `Result`.

---

В аннотации `@JoinColumn` вы указываете имя колонки, которая ссылается на `Primary Key` таблицы с результатами. Когда `hibernate` видит эту аннотацию, он смотрит в какой таблице лежит объект `Result` и достает оттуда значение по указаyному `id`.

---

Это проще объяснить на примере `jdbc`.

Есть запрос `SELECT * FROM BETS as b LEFT JOIN RESULTS as r ON b.id_result=r.id_result;`

Из него мы получаем таблицу в которой есть все поля относящиеся к `Bet` и к `Result`. Идем по результату построчно и разбираем каждую строку на объект:

```
while(resultList.next()){
    Bet bet = new Bet();
    bet.setIdBet(resultList.getInt("id_bet"));
    //мапим все поля bet через сеттеры, кроме result

    Result result = new Result();
    result.setIdResult(resultList.getInt("id_result"));
    //мапим все поля result через сеттеры

    bet.setResult(result);
    //теперь у нас есть полностью готовый объект bet     
}
```

Hibernate все это делает за вас (+ ленивую загрузку). Т.е. в  `@JoinColumn` вы указываете колонку, которая в `JOIN` будет равна `id` присоединяемой таблицы.